# Ubuntu 17.04 won't boot

Tags: boot, unity8, 17.04

Earlier this afternoon I updated to Ubuntu 17.04, after reboot it had worked fine. However I decided to try out the new Unity 8 desktop as I was using gnome prior, but when I logged out, selected Unity 8 and logged back in I was faced with a black screen. After half an hour I decided to reboot. Now my computer is stuck loading, the last output reads:

```
    [  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown
```

Please advise on what has gone wrong and how I might rectify it.

Update: I am not sure if the output is of any significance as having rebooted it gets to different point before stalling

Update: I have managed to boot from recovery mode to the old ubuntu desktop, it appears to be an issue with Unity 8 as I still can't boot to it. This issue would appear to be different to the one that thispost is about so I will ask a more specific question.